# Troubleshooting BLDC gate driver with PIC16F

Tags: pic, brushless-dc-motor, mosfet-driver, gate-driving, motordriver

Attached is a simplified single phase (repeated for all 3 phases) schematic. I have simulated a 6 step block commutation (trapezodial) using LEDs as high/low steps; rotor feedback from a small motor that has hall sensors incorporated. I want to safely test the driver board before connecting a motor.

Using a high-voltage LED, I PWM Phase A high-side and Phase B low-side on to see if the LED works (bootstrap recharge 99% duty cycle). Using a PSU, I supplied 12v to the driver ICs and 12v to MOSFET drain at the high-side. LED would turn on for a second then the amperage on the PSU began to increase (voltage dropped). The board failed (smoked at low-side IC).
Clearly I am doing something wrong.

Questions:

- Does this driver setup not allow for continuous operations such as
  keeping an LED on?
- During 6-step commutation, should the high-side PWM be a very quick pulse and immediately onto the next step? Or should I incorporate a time delay?
- What is a basic way to test the driver board without connecting a motor to it?
- Are my connections in the schematic catastrophic? Seemed to work for a quick few seconds.
- Should MOSFET side power be isolated from gate drivers? Meaning, should I not supply the same 12v to the drivers and MOSFET top drain?

Link to spec sheets:

1. [ROHM gate drivers](https://fscdn.rohm.com/en/products/databook/datasheet/ic/power/gate_driver/bd2320efj-la-e.pdf)
2. [MOSFETs](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/308/1/FQU13N10L_D-1810105.pdf)
3. [PIC16F18025 MCU](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/MCU08/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/PIC16F18015-25-44-45-Microcontroller-Data-Sheet-40002340B.pdf)

Below is a simple code I used to get started.

- PWM period (s) = 0.000032
- PWM Frequency (Hz) = 31250
- PWM Resolution = 10bits

```
#include "mcc_generated_files/system/system.h"

int main(void)
{ 
    SYSTEM_Initialize();

    while(1)
    {
        //trigger spring loaded potentiometer
        if(ADCC_GetSingleConversion(analog_input)>10)
        {
            PWM3_LoadDutyValue(ADCC_GetSingleConversion(analog_input));
            phase_v_lowside_SetHigh();
        }else{
            PWM3_LoadDutyValue(0);
            phase_v_lowside_SetLow();
        }
    } 
}
```

[image: schematic]

Comment: Please include links to component datasheets. https://fscdn.rohm.com/en/products/databook/datasheet/ic/power/gate_driver/bd2320efj-la-e.pdf Hi-Lo gate drivers need sufficient duty cycle to keep the bootstrap capacitor charged. Try adding a resistor in series with the Hi-Lo pairs so cross-conduction won't destroy anything. Then troubleshoot and show scope waveforms.

Comment: Thank you I went ahead and added the links to original post. I used Cg=Qg/Vq1g to calculate bootstrap capacitor at .22uF slightly higher: 
https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slua887/slua887.pdf?ts=1674490202298&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F

Can you show a simple example of the resistors you are referring to Paul? Thank you so much.

Comment: Just add a resistor of 1 ohm or so between the drain of Q2 and the point you call Phase A. If you get cross-conduction, where both Q1 and Q2 are on, it will limit the current to 12 amps (but 144 watts!). A better way might be to use something like a 12V automotive headlight bulb, which will probably have only about 0.1 ohm cold but will be able to withstand the current, and provide a strong indication of the problem.

Comment: Ok I went ahead and recreated with IR2101 on breadboard and it works. I think the other driver was maybe not soldered well onto the pads and had short circuited somehow. I got the LED to properly work and I attached to motor. It would whine with the but barely spun at 12v. I think I just need to work on commutation code now. Thanks for the help.